# How to enable video OR photo inside a background-image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this :

```
                       <div class="Photo" id="Photo1" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/850);"></div>
```

So I can load into it dynamically images.

```
    document.getElementById("Photo1").style.backgroundImage='url('+data[0]+')';
```

But, some users prefer photos and some videos. 
I would like to create a div/style that enables both video or photo to be loaded dynamically (so it can be a photo or a video )

Comment: The background color of an item cannot be a photo *and* a video at the same time. You'd have to ask the user which they prefer, then supply the relevant media.

Comment: Create two `<div>` tags, one for image and one for video, and then conditionally show/hide one of them, depending on user preference.

Comment: Hum... If I'm not mistaken, only Firefox allows to have a video as an element's background-image, and it needs to be somewhere in the DOM already.

Comment: thanks, so Tim, you say I should put the on top of each other ? I have one container that can be video or photo case by case .

Answer (score 0):

for video background via CSS with simple way check that video and there is alternative with js & jquery

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=05ZHUuQVvJM